# Breakpoints not Working when Using vsjitdebugger to Attach Debugger

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, vsjitdebugger

I have a C# application that is using vsjitdebugger to attach a debugger to another process using its pid, like this:

```
vsjitdebugger -p {pid}
```

When I do this the debugger selector pops up, and I pick the instance of Visual Studio that has the project I want to debug open.

Everything appears to work, Visual Studio does attach, but no breakpoints are working.

If I manually attach using Debug > Attach to process... it works as expected.

How can I get vsjitdebugger to work the same way as Debug > Attach to process...?

Answer (score 1):

This answer was the one that made it for me: ["skipped loading symbols for ngen binary" for C# dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169558/skipped-loading-symbols-for-ngen-binary-for-c-sharp-dll)

Basically when the debugger pops up, check the box that says:

> Manually chose the debugging engine

Then just check the one that fits. If you don't know which one it is, when you attach to process and the `.dll` loads properly, go to `Debug > Windows > Modules`, and you'll be able to see in the details.